# How to send email notification using azure to user group when there are records in a table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

.I am using azure sql database with my app hosted in azure
I tried using a Automation account, created a runbook but doesnt fetch any results

FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFound Exception.
CategoryInfo :Object Not Found: (SqlAutomation/RB_Record_AzureScheduler) Command Not Found exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "when an item is created" and the "when an item is modified" triggers for SQL in Azure Logic App to react to data changes.

[image]

You can add condition and choose an action like sending an email.

[image]

The SQL connector in Azure Logic Apps uses a polling mechanism to query a table for changes using a TIMESTAMP / ROWVERSION column. This data type is specifically designed for this kind of processing in SQL. The polling query essentially selects all rows where the rowversion is greater than the last polled value. The behavior is reliable since the column is controlled by SQL Server and the performance is extremely fast in the case where there is no new data. When there is new data, the performance is comparable to a simple row query.

For more information, please read [this](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/) article and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) one too.

Comment: Most helpful, i used azure logic to implement this using a workflow.